# Redux Sagas, Put Same Action In Parallel Multiple Times

Tags: redux, react-redux

How can I `put` the same action type multiple times in parallel, and be able to `take` all the responses?  In Redux's documentation, they use `call`, and `all` to make API calls in parallel, but from what I've read, reducers are only called when actions are dispatched.  How can I dispatch the same action in parallel, fetch every action's result, and have reducers be called?

```
# api/actions.ts
const getUserRequest = createAction('GET_USER_REQUEST', { userId });
const getUserSuccess = createAction('GET_USER_SUCCESS', { user });

# api/sagas.ts
function* fetchUser(action) {
  const user = axios.get(`api.example.com/users/${action.payload.userId}`;
  yield put({type: GET_USER_SUCCESS, user.data});
}

# api/reducers.ts
function (state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case: GET_USER_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.userId] = {}
      };
    case: GET_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.userId] = {...action.payload}
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

# ui/sagas.ts
function* fetchSelectedUsers(userIds: number[]){
  # I'm stuck at this saga.  How can I get multiple users, have reducers invoked, and perform additional processing in this saga after they've been retrieved?
  const actionsToDispatch = userIds.map(x =>
    put(getUserRequest({userId}))
  );

  yield all(actionsToDispatch);

  # Pseudo code
  const users = yield take(actionsToDispatch);
  users.map(x => {
    // Perform additional work from users that were returned.  Reducers must also be called from the `yield all(actionsToDispatch);` from above.
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello Mike did you found any solution to this?

Comment: You can use `all` with multiple `put` inside it,
It's already answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071902/12204242